# Mac OS X Lion - forward all connections on port 22 to external ip 

Tags: osx-lion, proxy, nat

I need to forward all connection to any address port 22 to a different gateway (i.e. no default).
Firstly I suppose to do it with ipfw:

```
sudo ipfw add 5 fwd $EXTERNAL_IP,22 tcp from any to any 22 keep-state
```

But with Mac OS X Lion it seems do not work.
Anyway, looking at ipfw documentation I see it is deprecated and I should use pfctl.

So I have modified `/etc/pf.conf` file:

```
rdr proto tcp from $internal_ip to any port 22 -> $external_ip port 22
```

But with no luck.

Does anyone know how to translate or forward all connections generated by local applications to any address but port 22 to a different gateway/ip address?